# Golang запуск rsync команды не работает

Tags: linux, golang, rsync

Единственный код, который хоть как-то запускается, но тем не менее не отсылает пакеты: (переменная temp = admintest@192.168.0.27:/home/admintest/testAccept)

```
for _, path := range mapToRegistredPeople {
    cmd := exec.Command("rsync", "-avz", "/home/adminusertest/test/*.txt", temp)
    out, err := cmd.Output()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(string(out))
}
```

При запуске выдает он следующее:

```
exit status 23
sending incremental file list
```

При этом ничего не отправляет клиенту

Comment: Сама по себе команда в терминале работает?

Comment: Да, все работает, но именно через программу нет

Comment: @PakUula посмотрел код ошибки, пробовал менять уровень привилегий приложения, все равно не работает

Comment: От имени какого пользователя вы запускаете программу? У этого пользователя есть ssh доступ к `admintest@192.168.0.27`?

Comment: @PakUula уточните пожалуйста как понять это, если запустить команду через консоль, без чудо, тогда да, есть, если другим способом, тогда честно говоря, не знаю

Comment: Что-то у вас не так с настройками в системе. Я попробовал у себя - `rsync` работает и в командной строке, и через `exec.Command`